# Using syntax highlighter with tsx react markdown

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-markdown, react-syntax-highlighter

I'm following the Github https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown and am trying to add SyntaxHighlighter to my markdown code snippets. I'm getting an error mentioned below when trying to use the example code inside a function which I use to render the posts. Markdown is using three backticks and this uses NextJS.

If I comment out the line `{...props}` the red underline is removed but I dont see the code taking effect in my posts

Tried adding any as below but still I dont see any effect in the markdown.

`code({ node, inline, className, children, ...props }: any)`

Error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: SyntaxHighlighterProps | Readonly<SyntaxHighlighterProps>): SyntaxHighlighter', gave the following error.
    Type '{ ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLElement> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; defaultChecked?: boolean | undefined; defaultValue?: string | number | readonly string[] | undefined; ... 255 more ...; PreTag: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicClassAttributes<SyntaxHighlighter>'.
      Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
        Type 'LegacyRef<HTMLElement> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<SyntaxHighlighter> | undefined'.
          Type '(instance: HTMLElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<SyntaxHighlighter> | undefined'.
            Type '(instance: HTMLElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type
```

Code:

```
const BlogPost = ({ frontMatter, markdownBody }: BlogPostProps) => {
  if (!frontMatter) return <></>;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <ReactMarkdown
        components={{
          code({ node, inline, className, children, ...props }) {
            const match = /language-(\w+)/.exec(className || "");
            return !inline && match ? (
              <SyntaxHighlighter
                style={vscDarkPlus}
                language={match[1]}
                PreTag="div"
                // {...props}
              >
                {String(children).replace(/\n$/, "")}
              </SyntaxHighlighter>
            ) : (
              <code className={className} {...props}>
                {children}
              </code>
            );
          },
        }}
      >
        {markdownBody}
      </ReactMarkdown>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue today. It appears that their docs are all over the place. I see SyntaxHighlighter requires children, but you failed to add it as part of the tag. Below is my code snippet with props being commented out as you have also done. [This code snippet is an edit from remarkjs](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown#use-custom-components-syntax-highligh).

```
      <ReactMarkdown className="preview-markdown" 
      children={input}
      remarkPlugins={[[remarkGfm, {singleTilde: false}]]}
      components={{
        code({node, inline, className, children, ...props}) {
          const match = /language-(\w+)/.exec(className || '')
          return !inline && match ? (
            <SyntaxHighlighter
              children={String(children).replace(/\n$/, '')}
              style={docco}
              language={match[1]}
              PreTag="div"
              // {...props}
            />
          ) : (
            <code className={className} {...props}>
              {children}
            </code>
          )
        }
      }}
       />
```

Comment: Thank you thank you. This line specifically is what fixed me up after hours of troubleshooting. `children={String(children).replace(/\n$/, '')}` Interestingly, I had no problems if I passed the syntax highlighter to the Code component only.

Comment: I believe that is merely caused by typescript since it does not check to see if the code in that component is valid. From experience, I do not notice an issue until the code tries to run. I usually create a separate function that I can unit test and then reference the component inside of the code component.